# Google Cloud API - Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Utils::chooseHandler()

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, guzzle, google-api-php-client

I just installed the Google Cloud Storage for PHP (https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/cloud-storage/latest) using their recommended composer request (composer require google/cloud-storage). I also setup a service account for authentication and downloaded the json file like their authentication documents suggested (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/main/AUTHENTICATION.md).

Using the sample code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient([
        'keyFilePath' => '/path-to-key.json'
       ]);

$bucket = $storage->bucket('bucket_location');

print_r($bucket);
return false;
```

I get the error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Utils::chooseHandler() in ../guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php on line 61.

It seems like Guzzle isn't loading. The function is located in the Utils.php file under Guzzle.

I tried composer update, composer auto-dump, and in the error stack I can see the new StorageClient() function loads the json authentication file.

Anyone know what I can try to get Guzzle to load? When I run composer show I can see the Guzzle version is 7.7.0.

Here is my composer.json file contents:

```
    {
        "require": {
            "google/cloud-storage": "^1.33"
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you run `composer show` is `guzzlehttp/guzzle` listed as one of the installed packages? What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: yes when I run composer show I get guzzlehttp/guzzle (v7.7.0), guzzlehttp/promises (v2.0.0), and guzzlehttp/psr7 (v2.5.0). I have the site running locally on PHP 7.4.30-0118

Comment: Your code is correct, so you have a configuration problem. 1) Include composer.json in your post. 2) Is there a reason you are using PHP 7.4? That is an ancient version. I recommend using at least PHP 8.1. Your problem might be a simple as using too old of a PHP version which might not work with the current Google Cloud SDKs.

Comment: @JohnHanley I added the composer.json file content to the post. No real reason for still running PHP 7.4, code is a little older so need to go through and make sure everything works on 8 before upgrade. I believe the Google repo said this will work on PHP 7.4+. Thanks

Comment: The time to setup PHP 8 to see if that is your problem is not significant and most systems support multiple versions (Linux and Windows). I have a lot of experience with PHP and Google Cloud. I would not use PHP 7.x today. There is a limit to how much effort developers put into testing on versions that no longer have vendor support. PHP 7 is like Python 2, no longer worth the effort to make them work.

Comment: @JohnHanley I just updated local machine to 8.0, it still didnt fix my issue but the error stack showed more details... Looks like its conflicting with my Xero Accounting library. It also uses guzzle. Do you know a way for composer to use the different versions of Guzzle depending on if its Google or Xero?

Comment: Why would the code you posted be affected by Xero? That means there are some configuration details that you are leaving out. No, you cannot mix different versions of libraries for the same code base. However, I do not know how your application is structured, so there might be a way be using isolation (separate directories). If the code mixes, then you can't.

Comment: Xero was setup in a sub directory that also used composer, thanks for the tips. Looks like it was just a conflict with another library and nothing wrong with google cloud or the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki for others sake:

**Solution:**

1. Upgraded PHP version from 7.4 to 8.0 to get more detailed error information.
2. Identified the conflict between Google Cloud Storage and the Xero Accounting library, both using different versions of Guzzle.
3. Recognized that mixing different versions of libraries for the same code base is not possible.
4. Explored isolating the two libraries in separate directories to avoid conflicts.
5. Considered upgrading the Xero Accounting library to a version compatible with the Guzzle version used by Google Cloud Storage.

**Additional Information:**

PHP Version: 7.4.30-0118 (Updated to 8.0 later)

Composer Dependencies:

- google/cloud-storage: ^1.33
- guzzlehttp/guzzle: v7.7.0 (also guzzlehttp/promises and guzzlehttp/psr7)

There is another library, Xero Accounting, which also uses Guzzle and was set up in a subdirectory with Composer.

**Note:**

- PHP 8.0 or higher is recommended for compatibility with current Google Cloud SDKs and libraries.
- Mixing different versions of Guzzle in the same code base is not advisable and can lead to conflicts.

*Community Wiki – Referring to @John Hanley and @phpcoder*

Comment: Nice summary, thank you.